# Not possible to check Android Subscription status from webserver without manual login?

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, google-play, subscription

After thorough research it seems to me that it is currently not possible to check the status for a Google Play Android subscription from my php server on an automated basis (e.g. cronjob or subscription end) without having a manual login to generate an access token.

Is this correct? Am I the only one who feels that this a huge inconvenience if not a show breaker? I do not want to manually login every day on my webserver only to check for the subscriptions of Google Play.

See:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

Comment: There are instructions within the URL you posted that explains how to refresh your API token, so I don't understand what you mean by "manual login"?

Comment: Sorry I was under the impression that the refresh_token expires as well, but as this is not the case, no manual interaction is needed :)